# How are treasure goblin locations determined?

Tags: diablo-iii

I have played through Act 1 inferno more times than I can count. I've noticed that treasure goblins seem to reappear in similar areas. Their locations don't seem to be entirely random. For example, every time I've found a treasure goblin in the Forsaken Woods, he is always somewhere on the left side of the map, near the forest edge. The same can be said for the ones I've found in other areas of Act 1 as well. The exact spot they appear varies somewhat, but the actual location seems to be fairly uniform. I think it's pretty obvious that their locations may be predetermined. So my question is: are there spots where treasure goblins are more likely to appear? If so, where? Are there any other factors that may cause them to be more likely to appear?

Comment: Unfortunately, many of the "good" (near checkpoints) treasure goblins have been removed due to over farming.

Comment: Is there somewhere that I can read about this change? Just curious :)

Comment: And just for the record, the ones I've found aren't necessarily near checkpoints so I do think there are some other varibles as to where they appear.

Comment: Most of my data comes from reddit's /r/diablo, most treasure goblin changes seem to be undocumented hotfixes noticed by TG farmers. Since this is a very subjective source, I'll just let you read through the constantly changing data on TG's on reddit: http://www.reddit.com/r/Diablo/search?q=treasure+goblin&restrict_sr=on - but as far as I understand they have static (from a map perspective, but not from a "someone at Blizzard is changing the data" perspective) spawn point based on the map that was loaded for the area.

Answer (score 2):

The Act 2 goblin near Road to Alcarnus still exists as of June 18, though I had terrible luck getting anything from him.

Start the quest `City of Blood`, `Lair of the Witch` and look around the waypoint to find him, very high spawn chance. If you save a prisoner or two in the bonus side quest, you always start at the city entrance and can work your way around the waypoint area to clear it (and spot any goblins). As always, don't use followers or be really careful and run back once you see a goblin right at the edge of the screen.